# Do you know how to fix this graphical python code?

Tags: python, tkinter

It shoulds display numbers like a calculator, with buttons with "try" and "lower/higher", it is a simple guess a random number, and the button "lower/higher" if your guess is higher or lower, I'm a beginner, so don't roast me (: . Also I'll write down the error I receive with this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 82, in <module>
    lower_higher = Button(frame, text=guessed, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= lambda: try_guess(equation_text, guessed))
NameError: name 'guessed' is not defined
```

I'll paste the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import random
i = random.randint(1, 1000)


def button_press(num):

    global equation_text
    equation_text = equation_text + str(num)
    equation_label.set(equation_text)

def try_guess(equation_text, guessed):
    guess = equation_text
    x = 1
    if guess != i:
        if int(guess) > i:
            guessed = "higher"
            x = x + 1
        if int(guess) < i:
            guessed = "lower"
            x = x + 1
    else:
        equation_text = "You won!"

    global equation_label
    equation_label.set("")
    equation_text = ""

    total = str(eval(equation_text))
    equation_label.set(total)
    equation_text = total



window = Tk()
window.configure(bg='#987ff8')
window.title("Guess The Number")
window.geometry("500x500")

equation_text = ""


equation_label = StringVar()

label = Label(window, textvariable=equation_label, fg="white", font=('Times',20), 
bg="#880ff8", width=24, height=2)
label.pack()

frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

button1 = Button(frame, text=1, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(1))
button1.grid(row=0,column=0)

button2 = Button(frame, text=2, bg='#856ff8',height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(2))
button2.grid(row=0,column=1)

button3 = Button(frame, text=3, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(3))
button3.grid(row=0,column=2)

button4 = Button(frame, text=4, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(4))
button4.grid(row=1,column=0)

button5 = Button(frame, text=5, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(5))
button5.grid(row=1,column=1)

button6 = Button(frame, text=6, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(6))
button6.grid(row=1,column=2)

button7 = Button(frame, text=7, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(7))
button7.grid(row=2,column=0)

button8 = Button(frame, text=8, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(8))
button8.grid(row=2,column=1)

button9 = Button(frame, text=9, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(9))
button9.grid(row=2,column=2)

button0 = Button(frame, text=0, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: button_press(0))
button0.grid(row=3,column=0)

lower_higher = Button(frame, text=guessed, bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, 
command= lambda: try_guess(equation_text))
lower_higher.grid(row=3,column=1)

try_num = Button(frame, text="try", bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, command= 
lambda: try_guess(equation_text))
try_num.grid(row=3,column=2)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The line in the traceback is not the same as that in the posted code.  Also what is the difference between `lower_higher` and `try_num` buttons because they both call the same function with same argument?  Also passing `equation_text` (a string) into the function and update it inside the function will not update the global one.

Comment: "I'm a beginner, so don't roast me (: " Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. Your level of experience does not matter - the *question* matters, and it is *your responsibility* a) to ask it clearly and precisely; b) to learn how the site works before posting.

Comment: Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that things happen in order.  When you create your `lower_higher` button, the variable `guessed` does not yet exist, just as the message says.  (Technically, since `guessed` is just a local variable in `try_guess`, it's never going to be a global variable.)
You need to put your default text in there -- what you want it to say at the beginning.  I can't really guess what you were thinking with this; do you want it to say "Make a guess"?

```
lower_higher = Button(frame, text="Make a guess", bg='#856ff8', height=4, width=9, font=35, 
command= lambda: try_guess(equation_text))
```

You have `try_guess` accepting two parameters, but you're only passing one.  You should remove "guessed" from there.  Then, when you do come up with a value for `guessed`, you need to update the button to include that text:

```
lower_higher.config(text=guessed)
```

You can do that just before the `else:` in `try_guess`.  You probably want to update that label to say "You won!" if they did; as you have it now, that label will continue to say "higher" or "lower" even after they win.